# Copying multiple files in separate directories simultaneously in file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

My situation involves a lot more files, but consider the below simplified example of my scenario - 2 separate files, `img1.jpg` and `img2.jpg` are in completely different paths. I want to move both of them to the folder `Destination` at the same time.

It's a trivial command-line task, but I'm wondering if there's a GUI method to achieve the same outcome using file explorer in Windows.

See below:

```
Desktop
    |
    |___ PStuff
    |    |
    |    |__ img1.jpg
    |
    |___ Other stuff
    |      |
    |      |__ Another folder
    |          |
    |          |__ img2.jpg
    |
    |___ Destination     #Copy both files here simultaneously!
         |_
```

If these two files were in the same directory, I could just <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click each file and then move them wherever I want at the same time in file explorer - is it possible to do the same (or something similar) with two or more files in completely different directories, in the same situation as detailed above?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways that are closely related: selecting the items from a `Search Results` folder or from a `Library` ( Libraries are essentially pre-defined searches for all items within a given set of paths ). Libraries are under-appreciated as a Search tool. Their most useful feature, the alternate views available, are tucked away in a content menu.

**`Arrange by >`** , available from a Library background context menu, offers options that vary based on the Library Type: Documents, Generic, Music, Pictures, or Videos.

From a Generic Libray, you can arrange by TYpe and then select from Stacks --- virtual folders of all items of the same type from the source folders and all their subfolders:

[image]

[image]

Select a stack to select fron files of that type:

[image]

You can initiate a Search from any one of these views. And when you initiate a Search form a Library, you hve multiple **`Arrange by >`** options for  the 1Search Results1 folder as well:

[image]